# Which upgrades are worth it?

Tags: orcs-must-die

So far I have upgraded spikes, arrow wall and archers. But i'm nervous about my next upgrade as you can't reset your points and I don't use the other traps as much.

The arrow wall and archers seem worth it as I'm using them a lot. What other upgrades are worth it? are any to be avoided?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It depends on your play style.** I've seen some people max out guardians for upgrades and then take the weaver skills to buff them every level to a nice effect. I've seen others concentrate on other traps instead.

Personally, I like to bottleneck orcs with a combination of barricades and tar traps, then take them out with wall blades and clockwork maces. So, I've purchased those upgrades.

**I would stress that, in my experience, there are some traps that seem a bit underpowered and that could be ruled out when focusing on what play style works best for you and what upgrades to choose.**

- The steam trap is something I've never used. It seems to lack sufficient utility.
- Decoys and boom barrels are things I usually only use when I have an extra slot available as a "get out of jail free" card.
- Because of how the spore mushroom works, it seems a bit too random to be reliable.
- The spring trap and push trap are very situational.

Comment: If you're not keen on spring traps, try putting one at the very end of your tarry bottleneck: hilarity ensues.

Comment: @StuartPegg: I usually take the Wind Belt for such hilarity; it's more reliable.

Comment: I do too, but it's the unexpectedness that cracks me up.

Comment: I didn't like the spore traps but I've found them to be very useful on nightmare mode. I place them right before before an ogre steps on them. This is very effective with Armored Ogres, as not only you don't have to kill them, they will also kill a lot of enemies for you.